# Excel Insert Rows - Using Named Ranges To Hide Rows

Tags: excel, vba, rows, hidden

I have hidden rows with checkbox macros

Every time I want to insert a new row, the vba code gets messed up and the code assigned to hide rows below will not work

is there a way to dynamically have the rows change the code in the vba

So I don't have to redo all the row values and check boxes that move in the process

[IMG]http://i39.tinypic.com/2akek5z.jpg[/IMG]

---

Sub CheckBox1_Click()

```
If Range("B3").Value = True Then
    Rows("4:18").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else
    Rows("4:18").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
```

End Sub

Sub CheckBox2_Click()

```
If Range("B51").Value = True Then
    Rows("52:66").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else
    Rows("52:66").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
```

End Sub

I have about 10 subcheckboxes in the code

---

If I insert or delete a row the code below will not work.

This is because the rows have changed

from the original code that I wrote

Comment: In that case, you need to code to keep track of the additions, deletions and hiding/un-hiding  of the rows and use make use of the the dynamic row references

Comment: also, you should probably show us some code so that we can help you on your *real* issue

Comment: Hi, I am not sure what dynamic row references are

Answer (score 0):

***Edit***

Use 'Named Ranges' instead of hard coding the range.  The named range will automatically update when you insert a new row.  For example:

I selected rows 9 thru 13 and named them 'RowsABC' as shown here:

[image]

I also named my checkbox cell as 'CheckABC' so that it is no longer dependent on what row it's in.

Your code now looks like this:

```
If Range("CheckABC").Value = True Then
    Range("RowsABC").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else
    Range("RowsABC").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
```

Now you can select a row such as row 10 and right click -> insert, and your macro will hide rows 9:14 instead of 9:13 because the named range will update automatically when you insert.

Comment: Hi, thanks for comments, I will post some code for you from the excel sheet,I basically just want the code to update if I insert or delete rows

Comment: Hi, I dont know what iterate through them means, I will have to change a lot of code and am not sure how to do this